# move div up on mobile using push and pull bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying yo move neweyes class using push and pull on mobile screen but I am unable to do that. How can I move upside this on mobile screen?

```
<div>
   <div class="woke-eye col-sm-12 col-md-4  col-sm-push-12">
      <img id="dani1">
   </div>
   <div class="neweyese  col-sm-12  col-md-8   col-sm-pull-12">
      <img src=''/>
   </div>
```

> **EDIT**  working fiddle

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/5) the wokeup eyes div should come later on mobile. now code is doing reverse , on large screen its coming later . but I need on mobile

Comment: can you put the example code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @saiful  dont know how to setup on jsfiddle for it . How  I will post images and bootstrap library on it ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/2/

Comment: if you are targeting mobile screens then you should use `col-xs-*`

Comment: thank you @saiful    https://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/5/    the wokeup eyes div should come later on mobile.  now code is doing reverse , on large screen its coming later . but I need on mobile

Comment: @Cons7an7ine can you check my updated answer and fiddle  ?

Comment: @Cons7an7ine  xs pushing things on desktop aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using your code, but modified so that it works the way you want.

```
<div>
  <div class="neweyese col-md-4 col-md-push-8">
    <img src=''/>neweyese
  </div>
  <div class="woke-eye col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">
    <img id="dani1">woke-eye
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't need col-sm-12, because that is the default behavior if you don't include it. Otherwise, we're essentially reversing the position of the two columns on MD and up. If the viewport is below MD, then the columns will switch to a width of 12 but since they are reversed the one on the right will be on top.

https://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/12/

Comment: its changing on desktop , while I need this on mobile. same working

Comment: how can I do this on mobile ?

Comment: @Learner, this code as is will have the column on the right be the column on top for mobile.

Comment: its changing on desktop but not on mobile

Comment: @learner I updated my answer again. I think I finally got what you were trying to do.

Comment: its showing opposite , on Desktop  I want normal but it showing chaning , and on mobile its showing what I want on desktop

Comment: @Learner Ok, for clarity, let's use the names of the classes.

On mobile, you want neweyese on top or bottom? On desktop, do you want neweyese on the left or right side? Answer that and I'll get it right for you.

Comment: I want  neweyese on left on desktop , but bottom on mobile

Comment: you got it now ?

Comment: @Learner, yep, should be good to go. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: is this possible ?

Comment: if I want  woke-eye  on left on desktop  and  up on mobile ?

Comment: its last thing if you can guide ?

Comment: @Learner, 
If you want woke-eye on left and top on mobile, then you don't need push or pull. jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/13

Comment: I am watching stackoverflow answer classes. which are different you used on fiddle :(

Comment: yes you are right .I am asking about last which I asked . " if I want woke-eye on left on desktop and up on mobile"  can you tell me according to stackoverflow  answer ?

Comment: <div>
  <div class="woke-eye col-md-8">
    <img id="dani1">woke-eye
  </div>
  <div class="neweyese col-md-4">
    <img src=''/>neweyese
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want:

You want on desktop `.woke-eye` to be on left side and `.neweyese` on right, on small screen you want `.woke-eye` to be below `.neweyese`, If so here is an [updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/6/), hope this helps.

**Update**

Check the updated [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/14/).

**Second Update**

Reffering to your last comment, this is what you are looking for [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/15/).

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6rtwyazq/12/    I want class neweyess on left on desktop and  bottom on mobile in this fiddle

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .xs-column-reverse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```